# How can I make an If statement to check if textBox1.Text contains the string reply = client.DownloadString (address); properly?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to make a button that will check if `textBox1.Text` contains any of the text in my raw text file on Pastebin online for test purposes.

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string reply = client.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/0FHx1t5w");
    }
```

and for my button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string textbox = textBox1.Text;

    // Compile error on next line: 
    if (textbox.Contains(reply))
    {
    }
}
```

The string `reply` is marked red and says:

> The name 'reply' does not exist in the current context

Is it because `.Contains` doesn't support string check?

Comment: It's because variable "reply" exists only in the context of Form1 constructor, since it is local variable (you declared it there). Make it class field or declare it and download the value inside your button1_Click method.

Comment: Also, you would need to call `Contains` using the `Text` property of the `Textbox` (not the `Textbox` itself). And, `Contains` will return `true` if the **first** string contains the **second** string. In your case, it sounds like you want to check if the textbox text is contained in the raw text. If that's the case, you would use `if (reply.Contains(textbox.Text))`.

Comment: Hello Rufus L, I am getting an error "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value'" when i click the button with the line "if (textbox.Contains(reply))". I printed the reply string to console and it was fine.

Comment: Show your updated code.  Again, `if (textbox.Contains(reply))` is incorrect as the `textbox` does not have a definition for `Contains`.  You need to use `if (textbox.Text.Contains(reply))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of scope. `reply` is defined within `Form1`'s constructor. Once the constructor is exited, the `reply` variable is no longer valid.

You can declare the variable at the class level instead of within a method.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Declare it here
    private string reply;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        reply = client.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/0FHx1t5w");
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to access it from the button click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code to this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Now its a field, rename it appropriately later
    private string reply;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        reply = client.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/0FHx1t5w");



    }
```